# Diferença entre maneiras de se realizar um backup (Espaço em disco, buffer, etc)

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, backup

Suponhamos que tenho uma máquina com `10GB` de espaço em disco livre, e tenho um script de backup de um banco de dados `postgresql`, que quando executado, faz o backup localmente e logo após terminar, copia para um outro servidor remoto.

O problema é o seguinte, quando o backup alcança um tamanho igual ou maior a `10GB`, vai faltar espaço em disco e logo vai dar problema em tudo o que roda nessa máquina.

**Pergunta**: usando o `pg_dump` e ao invés de fazer o backup localmente, já fazer o backup apontando para outra máquina através da opção `-h`, mesmo se o tamanho total do backup for maior que `10GB`, o tamanho do buffer irá ser suficiente pra não travar a máquina em questão de espaço?

Comment: Esta pergunta pertence ao [DatabaseAdministrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @dcastro http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com

Comment: @dcastro `Áreas relacionadas ao dia a dia de programadores, como **administração de sistemas**`. Se uma pergunta sobre backup não fazer parte do dia-a-dia de um programador, retiro todos meus argumentos. kthxbay

Comment: No entanto, existe uma razao para fechar entitulada "esta pergunta nao e' sobre programacao". Na minha opiniao, este nao e' o sitio correcto para esse tipo de perguntas, e existem sitios melhores e mais apropriados. "kthxbay"? Nao e' preciso ficar chateado.

Comment: A pergunta é relevante e está dentro do escopo do "Estouro de Pilha" já que não há um site equivalente em português.

Comment: @jean Eu ate' concordo com a razao apresentada pelo MurifoX, mas "já que não há um site equivalente em português." nao e' valido. Tambem nao existe uma versao portuguesa do [Physics StackExchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), vais comecar a fazer perguntas de fisica aqui?

Comment: Eu acredito que o escopo deste site é TI, Engenharia e Desenvolvimento de Software. Se for sobre backup de uma base de dados para um sistema de Física sim!

Comment: Não quero estender muito, se precisarem continuar discutindo isso, por favor abram uma discussão no meta. Mas apesar do site ainda não estar com toda definição determinada e as ferramentas devidamente adequadas, o site é sobre **desenvolvimento de software**. Em princípio, nem mais, nem menos. O que faz parte disto ainda está sendo determinado. Alguns casos são óbvios, outros não: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que você de uma olhada na [documentação](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/backup.html) pra ter algumas idéias de como abordar o backup, mas basicamente temos três opções pra fazer backup:

- dump (através do utilitário [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html))
- file system (copia dos arquivos feitos via rsync/scp/etc)
- PITR (feito através de script customizado, [pg_rman](https://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/) ou até [pgbarma]n[4](http://pgbarman.org/))

Eu recomendo que tu dê uma olhada no artigo do fabio telles que fala sobre backup:
http://savepoint.blog.br/dump-nao-e-backup/

Comment: 2. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: 3. https://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/

Comment: 4. http://pgbarman.org

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o backup a partir de uma máquina remota que tenha postgresql-client instalado:

```
pg_dump -h postgres_server dbname >pg_dump.bkp
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um NFS para a máquina remota e realizar o backup normalmente, como faria em um diretório local.

O tempo do seu backup vai depender da velocidade do link entre o seu servidor local e o servidor remoto.

Se a velocidade deste link for menor do que a velocidade do seu sistema de arquivos local (por exemplo, você conseguiria gravar com o dobro da velocidade no disco local do que conseguiria na rede), lembre-se de habilitar a compactação máxima com o parâmetro `-Z 9`. Você só deixa de usar compressão se a velocidade do seu link for tão boa que não justifique perder tempo de processador comprimindo.